# Cannot see Pardot Activities in Salesforce Contact/Lead Record. Keeps getting prompted to enter Pardot credentials

Tags: salesforce1-app, single-sign-on, pardot

I have set up Salesforce Connector in Pardot and and also have Pardot App in my Salesforce Org.

I have set up Pardot Activites Vf Page in Contact and Lead. And every time it prompts me to enter the credentials. Is there any fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps [as pointed out in the Pardot Help](http://help.pardot.com/customer/portal/articles/2127367-mapping-salesforce-and-pardot-usernames-and-single-sign-on):

> 1. Navigate to Admin > User Management > Users.
> 2. Use the checkboxes on the left side of the table to select all users
>      you wish to enable single sign-on for.
> 3. From the dropdown at the bottom left of the users table, select
>      Enable single sign-on with CRM.
>
> You can also have your users follow these steps, if they wish to
>   enable single sign-on themselves:
>
> 1. Log into Pardot.
> 2. Hover over your email address in the top right to see your settings.
> 3. Click My Settings
> 4. Verify that your CRM username is correct.
> 5. If the CRM username is incorrect or absent, click Edit My User
>      Information, then click Link with Salesforce login to change or add
>      it.
> 6. If your username is correct, click Verify after the name.
> 7. Click Verify.
> 8. You will receive a message letting you know whether or not this was
>      successful.
> 9. If successful, log into Salesforce and click on the Pardot tab. You
>      should be able to go directly into the application without logging
>      into Pardot separately.
> 10. Each of your employees will need to perform these steps to utilize
>        the single sign on. Note that if your Salesforce username or
>        password changes, you will need to make the same change within
>        Pardot.

Comment: In short, you must enable SSO for each of your pardot users. Fred has outlined this above.